# img element does not stop loading when navigating to other components in angular

Tags: angular, mjpeg

I have an image on my component, that is showing a MJPEG.

```
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" src="{{imageUrl}}" />
```

When I navigate to another component, the request to the MJPEG is not cancelled.
It is still loading the images.

[image]

I have already tried to set the `imageUrl` in `ngOnDestroy` to `null`, or to a static image. Also I tried, to set the html element directly

```
this.image.nativeElement.src = null;
```

None of that is working. The download is still running.

Answer (score 0):

In you case `Obervable` must help. Request the image by url using `HttpClient` and then assign it to your `<img>`. Preserve the subscribtion and you will be able usubscribe it any time, which will cancel the request.